# maxscale doesn't see host for binlogrouter

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mariadb

not sure what I'm missing I'm following the documentation but it doesn't seem to know what the host is:

```
 2016-10-11 21:21:02   error  : Failure loading users data from backend [_none_:3306] for service [binlog]. MySQL error 2005, Unknown MySQL Server Host '_none_' (-2)
```

[link to my maxscale.cnf config](http://pastebin.com/hAcDFYTk)

confirmed network/grants work fine...what param am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

there needs to be a master.ini file within your maxscale binlog base directory that provides these parameters.